# изменить стиль блока

Tags: javascript, css

Есть div в котором список, нужно чтобы при наведении на элемент списка менялся стиль div с классом block.

```
 <div class="block"> 
   <div> 
      <ul >
       <li class="list"></li> 
       <li class="list"></li>  
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: $('.list').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
 $(this).closest('.block').css('background', 'red');
});

Answer (score 2):

Можно установить обработчик на элементы списка и, при наведении курсора, искать ближайший родительский элемент, соответствующий указанному селектору (*в вашем случае - класс "block"*)

```js
function closest(el, sel) {
  if (el !== null) {
    return el.matches(sel) ? el : (el.querySelector(sel) || closest(el.parentNode, sel));
  }
}

function toggleBg(e) {
  var parentBlock = closest(this, '.block');
  parentBlock.style.backgroundColor = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? '#ff0' : '';
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.list'), function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleBg, false);
  li.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleBg, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list">Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

А можно пойти от обратного. То есть, установить обработчик на родительский элемент, которому будем "перекрашивать" цвет фона и проверять на каком элементе событие сработало. Если данный элемент содержит класс "list", то меняем цвет фона.

```js
function toggleBg(e) {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('list')) {
      return false;
    }
    this.style.backgroundColor = e.type === 'mouseover' ? '#ff0' : '';
  }
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.block'), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', toggleBg, false);
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', toggleBg, false);
  });
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="list">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list">Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за потраченное время

Comment: Обязательно отмечу лучший ответ, когда попробую оба)

Answer (score 1):

Если пользуетесь jQuery, то можете поступить так:

```
var block = $('.block');
// делегировать обработку события на родительский контейнер
block
  // курсор на элементе с классом list
  .on('mouseover', '.list', function(){
    // какие-то действия с элементом .block, например добавление второго класса
    block.addClass('over');
  })
 // уход курсора с элемента с классом list
  .on('mouseleave', '.list', function(){
    block.removeClass('over');
  });
```

Comment: Благодарю за то, что уделили внимание.

Comment: Обязательно отмечу лучший ответ, когда попробую оба)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант с jQuery.

```js
$("#block li").hover(function(){
   $("#block").addClass('hover');
}, function(){
   $("#block").removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.block {
  color: #fff;
  background: #F00;
}

.block.hover {
  background: #000;
}

.block ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.block .list {
  background: blue;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block" class="block"> 
   <div> 
      <ul>
       <li class="list">Hello</li> 
       <li class="list">World!</li>  
      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
```